# d3.svg.line() issues

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

**JSFiddle Link:** http://jsfiddle.net/zDgsp/

I am very new to D3.js and I was trying to get a line chart working (actually, one with multiple lines). I've read the [d3 API reference](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-line) and a handful of tutorials a couple of times but still cannot figure out what my problem is. Usually I am really fast at adapting new things.

Drawing circles works fine but the line paths seem to be an issue. The DOM inspector shows me a number of path elements lying in my SVG, each with a size of `0px x 1px`.

When I do a `console.log()`'d the return values within the `line.x()` and `line.y()` handlers, I figured that these `console.log()`s weren't even called. That confuses me a lot because I'm doing exact the same thing as stated in the [API](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-line), except for replacing `x(d.x)` with `x(i)` and `y(d.y)` with `y(d)` because I'm using different data.

I also tried adding the "Z" string for the closed path but it all didn't really help.

How do I display those lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

last line: `.attr('d', line(dataset))`

because the line generator doesn't know which data to use.

Comment: I tried that just now but don't get it to work. Could you probably provide me a JSFiddle with the said code change? (For the original one see the first line of the question)

Comment: Oh my god, that was so stupid from me. I typed `line(data)` instead. Thanks for your help!